# Faulty power button on an iphone 3g and upgrade to 4.1

Tags: jailbreak, upgrade

I have a jailbroken 3.1.3 iPhone 3G with a faulty power button. I would like to upgrade it to the newest version of iOS possible, but obviously it needs to be done without using said power button - can it be done? And if so, what would be the best way to approach it?

Comment: Faulty how? And why would you need the power button?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the details of your question - but you can use '[Activatior](http://isource.com/2010/02/01/activator-a-free-and-extremely-powerful-jailbreak-app-launcher-for-iphone-jailbreak-apps/)' to give another button all the funcationality of the power button. (one of the volume switches perhaps)